# django_plotly_dash, plotly dash url navigation not working

Tags: django, plotly, plotly-dash

I am building dashboard using plotly dash.

For the web framework I have used Django framework for authentication and embedding other applications.

Integrated the plotly dash with the Django using the django_plotly_dash library.

I tried integrating the dash app into django using the django_plotly_dash package.

**plotly dash navigation:**

```
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample',
    external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SOLAR, dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

profile_menu = dmc.Menu(
            [
                dmc.MenuTarget(dmc.Avatar("BR", color="blue",radius="xl",id="user_profile_dropdown")),
                dmc.MenuDropdown(
                    [
                        dmc.MenuItem(
                            "Profile",
                            href="/my-profile",
#                             target="_blank",
                            icon=DashIconify(icon="streamline:interface-user-profile-focus-close-geometric-human-person-profile-focus-user"),
                        ),
                        dmc.MenuItem(
                            "Logout",
                            icon=DashIconify(icon="majesticons:logout-half-circle"),
                            href='/logout',
                            id='logout-button'
                        ),
                    ]
                ),
            ],
        trigger="hover",
#         position='top-end',
        style=right_align_style,
    )

app.layout = html.Div([
      profile_menu 
])
```

**welcome.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    {% comment %} <h1>Dash Home page</h1> {% endcomment %}
    <body>
        {% load plotly_dash %}
        <div class="{% plotly_class name='SimpleExample' %} card" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">
            {% plotly_app name='SimpleExample' ratio=0.65 %}
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

SimpleExample is my DjangoDash app name.

**Django urls:**

```
urlpatterns = \[
path('',views.home, name='home-page'),
path('login',views.login_user.as_view(), name='login-url'),
path('plotly_home',views.dash, name='plotly-home'),
path('logout',views.logout_user, name='logout-url'),
path('django_plotly_dash', include('django_plotly_dash.urls'))
\]
```

plotly_home endpoint will render the welcome.html page which shows the dash app.

**Output:**
[image]

**Problem:**
By default it renders my dash app inside the html Iframe.
Thus, any changes or URL changes won't be reflected outside that Iframe. So the plotly dash navigation links are not working.

I have one logout button where href='/logout' which is endpoint in the django. So when you hit /logout it should go to the logout endpoint. But no event is happening.

**Expectation**
When I click logout button of dash then it should redirect to the logout url endpoint.
Only plotly dash alone navigation working but integrating with django using django_plotly_dash library it's not working.

Any help is appreciated!
Thank you!